# Cannot filter index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my `pivot_device_T.Index`, my dataframe is `pivot_device_T`

```
Index(['', '3', 'AXIS', ... , 'All_Bolt', 'All_Telkomsel', 'All_XL', 'All_Indosat', 'All_Smartfren'],
      dtype='object', name='operatorName')
```

What I'm doing is

```
pivot_device_T = pivot_device_T[pivot_device_T['index'].str.contains("All")]
```

But what I get is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2441             try:
-> 2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2443             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: 'index'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-18-aea8005e79dc> in <module>()
          1 pivot_device_T = pivot_device.T
    ----> 2 pivot_device_T = pivot_device_T[pivot_device_T['index'].str.contains("All")]
          3 #pivot_device = pivot_device_T.T

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
       1962             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
       1963         else:
    -> 1964             return self._getitem_column(key)
       1965 
       1966     def _getitem_column(self, key):

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
       1969         # get column
       1970         if self.columns.is_unique:
    -> 1971             return self._get_item_cache(key)
       1972 
       1973         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
       1643         res = cache.get(item)
       1644         if res is None:
    -> 1645             values = self._data.get(item)
       1646             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
       1647             cache[item] = res

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
       3588 
       3589             if not isnull(item):
    -> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
       3591             else:
       3592                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
       2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
       2443             except KeyError:
    -> 2444                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
       2445 
       2446         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

    pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

    pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

    KeyError: 'index'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pivot_device_T.index`, because `pivot_device_T['index']` select column names `index` and because not exist it raise error:

```
pivot_device_T = pivot_device_T[pivot_device_T.index.str.contains("All")]
```

Another solution should be [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
pivot_device_T = pivot_device_T.filter(like='All', axis=0)
```